# Rewriting function in Warren textbook

Tags: functions, trigonometry

Not exactly sure how to phrase the title, because the question I have is rather specific and I think requires a bit of background. The question is about the rewriting of a function that appears in B.E. Warren's *X-Ray Diffraction* on page 43, specifically about the rewrite from the second to third state, in the progression shown below: 
$$\sin^2{\pi\over\lambda}(\lambda\mathbf H_{hkl}+\Delta\mathbf S)\cdot N_1\mathbf a_1 = \sin^2\pi \biggl(hN_1+{\Delta\mathbf S \cdot N_1 \mathbf a_1\over\lambda}\biggr)= \sin^2{\pi\over\lambda}\Delta\mathbf S \cdot N_1 \mathbf a_1,$$
where
$$\mathbf H_{hkl} =( h \mathbf b_1 +k \mathbf b_2 +l \mathbf b_3) \,\, ; \,\, \mathbf b_i \cdot \mathbf a_i = 1.$$
I know this isn't much information and I'm not sure what's exactly relevant to this specific function, but I'll provide any necessary information upon request. To me, the subject of the $\sin^2$ term is a little unclear, but that's how it's written in the book. I'm having trouble following the apparent disappearance of the $hN_1$ term, to be specific. Any help is appreciated, many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that both $h$ and $N_1$ are integers, in which case this follows from the relation $$\sin^2 \pi(h N_1 + x)=\sin^2 \pi x$$ which holds for all real $x$.

We can establish the previous relation by considering $$\sin(x+\pi) = -\sin x,$$
which implies $\sin^2(x+\pi)=\sin^2 x$ and hence $\sin^2(x+n\pi)=\sin^2 x$ for all integers $n$ by induction.

Hope this answers your question!

Comment: Thanks very much, that hadn't occurred to me, and yes, $N_1$ and $h$ are integers in this case.